# C++ static data member initialization error in Eigen

Tags: c++, initializer-list, static-initialization

I'm using gcc-10 and Eigen 3.3.9 on Ubuntu 18.04. This snippet compiles and runs fine:

```
struct S {
  static inline Eigen::Vector3f u{1, 1, 1};
};

int main() {
  Eigen::Vector3f u(1, 1, 1);
}
```

but the latter version of initialization when applied to static data member, fails to compile:

```
struct S {
  static inline Eigen::Vector3f u(1, 1, 1);
};
```

with this error message: `error: expected identifier before numeric constant`.

Why is that?

Comment: I was looking for a dup, but couldn't find one... This is because you can't use parens to specify default values for member variables, because that would conflict with a function declaration. Consider the difference between `static inline int x(int);`, `static inline y(5);` and `static inline z{6};`.

Comment: That's a bit surprising, since you can't declare a function as `f(3)`, with numeric constant in place of type name. Oh well, one more weird thing in C++.

Comment: Once the compiler sees the `(` character in this context, it knows it is looking at a function prototype. It does not look ahead to make that determination. Allowing it would lead to _more_ confusing code. What would `int RGB(COLOR);` be - a function call or variable declaration? You wouldn't be able to tell without knowing what `COLOR` is (which could possibly an enum constant or a type), and its meaning could change depending on what other code was included before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the [paper that added the feature](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2756.htm), it was desired that default member initializers support **forward lookup** for consistency with (constructors’) member initializers.  However, member function parameter lists are *not* such a complete-class context.  That leads to ambiguity between function and variable declarations:

```
int I() {return -7;}
struct A {
  int x(I());
  typedef int I;
};
```

If `A::x` is a variable, then lookup for `I` finds the type `A::I`, which means that the declaration of `x` can be interpreted as a function declaration (accepting a function pointer), so it’s a function.  If it’s a function, lookup for `I` doesn’t consider (the subsequent) `A::I`, so `I` is `::I` and `A::x` declares a variable initialized to -7.  Interchanging `::I` and `A::I` gives **two** self-consistent interpretations instead of none.

There’s a rule that a class must not change the meaning of any name lookup performed in its definition, but it’s not clear whether it would apply here since under the variable interpretation the lookup would not change.  Instead, the syntactic possibility was simply excluded entirely even though there are of course cases where it would be entirely unambiguous.